# Plank dock in XFCE covers xfce-panels

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, window-manager, plank

I've installed the Plank dock in XFCE. It works OK except I use it vertically like to have the dock that the full height available.

When Plank is focused (ie: when you click on an app icon), Plank will cover XFCE's top panel, as you an see here:

[image]

Is there a way I can tell Plank to display itself below other Windows, or another way to make sure my top panel is always on the foreground?

Comment: I have the same problem with budgie, it covers the top panel completely. Have you find a solution or workaround?

Comment: @Felipe unfortunately no, I dropped Plank/XFCE because of it and I'm back to using awesome with a coded panel

Comment: can you explain what "awesome" is? maybe what you're doing might also work for me.

Comment: It's "awesome window manager". It's a tiling window manager. Takes a bit of getting used to but in the long run I find it keeps your desktop more organised. It's heavily shortcut-based and it's definitely not for everyone. Google should show you what it looks like.